# Why amazon emails goes to spam

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, cakephp, amazon-ses

I have domain with 1&1 and my host is on AWS. I have configured my domain in Route5 and I set MX records. as per below:

```
10 mydomain.co.uk
10 mx01.1and1.co.uk
10 mx00.1and1.co.uk
```

The email transfer is working without any problem. The email are stored in 1&1 mail bucket.

I have an application that runs on Cakephp and here is my email Transport configuration.

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Mailer\Transport\MailTransport',
        /*
         * The following keys are used in SMTP transports:
         */
        'host' => 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
        'port' => 465, // or 587
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'info@mydomain.co.uk',
        'password' => '*****',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => true,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
```

Now when I send emails the emails are sent to client account but the emails goes in spam. and I get red rock - email not encrypt.

Here is the example of the mail transfer from client account:

```
from:   Company Name Ltd <info@mydomain.co.uk>
to: Alex Manor <alex.manor@gmail.com>
date:   Jan 21, 2019, 11:13 PM
subject:    You have requested to reset password
security:    ec2-11-11-11-11.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com did not encrypt this message Learn more
```

Comment: Why are you not using the SMTP transport instead of Mail? And why are you using localhost instead of your domain's registered mail server? (Or, at least, trying to use localhost; all your configuration after `className` is ignored because you're not using SMTP.)

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you for answer. I have updated my email config.  I have changed the transport by adding `'transport' => 'smtp'`after host. I ahve change the  `className` to use transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to  @Greg Schmidt.

```
'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Mailer\Transport\SmtpTransport',  //<= The class name has to use SMTP
        'host' => 'smtp.ionos.co.uk',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'info@mydomain.co.uk',
        'password' => '*****',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => true, 
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
```

After too much reading now I know you wouldn't need to change  you host provider for email transport. As long as the email email transport methos is set correctly. you shouldn't get red lock.

Here is a good guide to configure the email DNS transfer

1. Log into 1and1 and go to Manage domains.
2. The domain was    currently set to use 1&1 name servers with MX records of    mx00.1and1.co.uk mx01.1and1.co.uk
3. Logged into Amazon Route 53.
4. Created a hosted zone for my domain.
5. Clicked Created record set    then used the MX records from 1and1 i.e., 0 mx00.1and1.co.uk and 1    mx01.1and1.co.uk - This was
   the important bit which ensured I didn't    lose my inbound email
6. Went into SES and selected the option to use    Route 53 which created my CNAME and TXT records automatically in    Route53
7. As I had the 1and1 MX records set up in Route53 now, I    could then go back to 1and1 and change the DNS settings to use other
   name servers, then entered my Amazon Route53 name servers instead.

**Note:** point #6 is good for who wants to use AWS host for email transport.